# Activity with a visible software keyboard

Tags: android, android-activity, android-softkeyboard, visible

I've seen some similar questions here but haven't found what I was really looking for. I need to create a simple activity where the user must enter a number and return it to the main activity. The layout should contain only an edit text on the upper half of the screen and a software keyboard on the lower half of the screen. The activity should finish when the Done key is pressed on the keyboard. Will appreciate any links or code snippets to help resolve this issue.

Comment: Look up the android tutorials, this is all on the dev site.

Comment: @JoxTraex, Please post the link if you know where exactly this question is described

Comment: Its not about **THIS** question. its about the fragments to SOLVE your task. Your task needs to be broken up into bits and handle it from there. Learn the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use a [Custom dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) to do it.

The point is, you want a keyboard to interaction, and return when a number is pressed, aren't you?

If want an example, you can create a Dialog Activity like:

```
public class Keypad extends Dialog

protected static final String TAG = "Keypad" ;
private final View keys[] = new View[9];
private View keypad;
private int tecla = 0;
```

Then set the this content on create:

```
setContentView(R.layout.keypad);
    findViews();
    setListeners();
```

find views will be something like this:

```
keypad = findViewById(R.id.keypad);
    keys[0] = findViewById(R.id.keypad_1); ...
```

And the dialog XML must have a table:

```
<TableRow>
    <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="keypadClick"
    android:text="keypadClick"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_2"
        android:text="2" >
    </Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/keypad_3"
        android:text="3" >
    </Button>
</TableRow> ... Etc
```

So, when you launch the dialog, appear a menu with 9 numbers (in my case) whom dismiss when push 1 of then, and dismiss the dialog (return to the point where was throw)

I hope it help!!

Comment: Pretty nice approach, I'll try this!